# Actualizar múltiples registros a la vez con listas c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Tengo una base de datos con una tabla llamada `Documento` con los campos `id`, `nombre del documento` y `fecha de creación`, además, tengo un `DataGridView` con un botón editar que hace lo siguiente:

```
bDocumentos[indexDocumento].NombreDocumento = txtNomDoc.Text;
```

...que es asignar el valor que tenga ese TextBox al nombre del documento seleccionado.

Luego quiero que al guardar, se efectúe ese cambio así:

```
public static void insertarDocumento(BindingList<Documento> documento)
{
    Entities context = new Entities();
    foreach (var doc in documento)
    {
        context.Documento.Add(doc);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Pasándole la lista con el dato modificado, pero me arroja la siguiente excepción:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

¿Alguna idea de cuál puede ser el error?

Comment: ¿Cuál sería la razón de volver a agregar la misma información de documentos nuevamente al contexto? ¿No solo deberían agregarse aquellos que son nuevos? Por lo que entiendo lo que requieres es un `UPDATE` de los que han cambiado, ¿es correcto?

Comment: Exácatamente eso es lo que quiero hacer!

Comment: El error  te dice que las instancias de `Documento` todavía están ligadas a otro `DbContext`, por lo que no pueden ser agregadas al `context` en este método. La solución no es clara, porque necesitaríamos ver lo que sucede antes de llamar `insertarDocumento`. Pero lo que dice @Flxtr parece ser la idea correcta. También toma en cuenta que, si este código es un reflejo del resto del código que tienes, es posible que parte del problema es que no le estás haciendo un `Dispose()`  a los contexts que creas, usando un bloque `using` por ejemplo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con la sentencia `context.Documento.Add(doc);` estás agregando nuevos documentos a la entidad, por eso el error, dados tus comentarios lo que requieres es que se actualicen los que estás modificando.

Supongo que por el nombre de tu método `insertarDocumento` te funciona perfecto para crear un nuevo registro, entonces para la edición, también deberías tener su equivalente:

```
public static void editarDocumento(Documento documento)
{
    using(context = new Entities())
    {
        context.Documento.Attach(documento);
        var registro = context.Entry(documento);
        registro.Property(t => t.NombreDocumento).IsModified = true;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Pues te comento que probé la función y me sigue tirando la misma excepción. Cómo te comente, tengo todo en una lista, por lo que hice un foreach para cada elemento de la lista (bDocumento<Documento>). Es decir:
foreach(var lista in bDocumento)
{
editarDocumento(lista);
}

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "todo en una lista"? Algo así como los que agregas y editas en el `GridView`?

Comment: Cómo te comente, tengo todo en una lista, por lo que hice un foreach para cada elemento de la lista (bDocumento<Documento>). Es decir:
foreach(var lista in bDocumento)
{
editarDocumento(lista);
}

Comment: Olvidenlo, leí el comentario de @sstan y al agregar un el using, funcionó de maravilla, gracias a ambos :D

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
foreach (var doc in documento)
{
    Entities context = new Entities();
    context.Documento.Add(doc);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```